# Cache object in Android?

Tags: android, object, caching

Im wondering whats the best way to cache objects in an Android application? I am working with a REST application and have written a notification class that fetches number of new messages, events, guestbookposts etc from our API in JSON-format.

I use these numbers to display a badge on the icons so users can see if they have any new undread messages, events etc...

I would however like to cache this object for about 5 minutes or so to save performance, but its not as easy as just to set an expire date on the sharedpreferences class...so how do i do it i ask you?

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of options, your choice depends on application needs:

- caching using [SQLite database](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)
- caching to a file (internal/external storage)
- [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) util from support package

If you're going to cache images, you can use one of 'all-in-one' libraries:

- [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
- [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

If you use `HttpUrlConnection` class to interact with server, take a look at [HttpResponseCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html) class.

But none of these options provide built-in support of setting cache lifetime, you have to implement it by yourself if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. However the cache lifetime is pretty essential for me so i went with SharedPreferences after all and a custombuilt timerclass.